# How to ensure piping is fully completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I'm currently working with streams in Node.js where I'm grabbing an image from my DB, using `node-canvas` to make some changes to the image, and then saving the image locally in my project. I want to be absolutely sure that the piping is fully complete before saving the image (to not get cut-off images). How can I do this?

**My Attempt**

```js
async function makeCanvas(img, code, channel) {
  const canvas = createCanvas(900, 1375);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 1255, 900, 120);
  // ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 1375);
  let image = await loadImage(img);
  ctx.font = "bold 100px 'Unisans Heavy'";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fillText(`${code}`, 435, 1350);
  const writeable = fs.createWriteStream(`./temp/${channel.id}.png`);
  const readable = canvas.createPNGStream();
  const pipeConnect = await readable.pipe(writeable);
  let ended;
  let path;
  await readable.on("end", () => {
    ended = readable["_readableState"].ended;
  });

  if (ended) {
    path = writeable.path;
  } else {
    console.log("File not ready.");
  }
return path;
}
```

I'm trying to reassign the `ended` variable to see if the operation has ended, and if it is ended, then doing something with it. But it seems like I can't reassign the value of `ended` in the event listener. What could I do instead?

Comment: I don’t think you can await readable.on(), because it doesn’t return a promise. This needs a little refactoring. Do you want to keep using await or do you want to use callbacks?

Comment: @schteppe I'd like to use await if possible!

Answer (score 0):

```
await readable.on(“end”, ...
```

This is not something you can await, because it does not return a Promise. To make it possible to use await, consider using `require('events').once`. Like this:

```
await once(readable, "end");
```

See [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events_once_emitter_name).